# What am I? I am here

Tags: riddle

I am here,
yet most people don't care,

I kill people,
if you are not careful.

I can be created,
but it's rather useless.

If you can see me,
It's because of Him.

What am I?

Hint:

> Him does not refer to a scientist or God

Hint 2:

> The first 3 clues directly describe the answer. The last clue describes the answer, but not in the same way as the previous clues.

Hint 3:

> "Him" is a Mexican.

Comment: I might have made a mistake. The answer to the riddle can actually be created, at least in theory.  But no one has ever create it in any significant amount.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think It could be

> Gravity

I am here,
yet most people don't care,

> Gravity is everywhere, but most people don't actually think about it

I kill people,
if you are not careful.

> you can fall off a cliff or something can fall onto you

I can be created,
but it's rather useless.

> Gravity can be created (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artificial_gravity)

If you can see me,
It's because of Him.

> The movie "Gravity" was written by Alfonso Cuarón, a Mexican.

Comment: That's the one. Well done.

Answer (score 8):

> Energy?

*I am here, yet most people don't care,*

> Many people waste their energy.

*I kill people, if you are not careful.*

> Energy can be used for all sorts of things, including killing people.

*I cannot be created, nor can I be destroyed.*

> The law of [conservation of energy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conservation_of_energy).

*If you can see me, It's because of Him.*

> $E=mc^2$. Either "see"$=c$ or "see" as in light ($c$ is the speed of light). This is due to Einstein, often held up as a model of brilliance.

Comment: Right train of thoughts, but not the right answer.

Answer (score 1):

Is it:

> Sunlight?

I am here,
yet most people don't care,

> Yea it's warm and, free..

I kill people,
if you are not careful.

> Sunburn N degree

I can be created,
but it's rather useless.

> Not too sure, "Sunlight" can be created by mimic the same fusions from sun?

If you can see me,
It's because of Him.

> HIM as Heliocentric Information Map?

What am I?

> Sunlight?

Answer (score 0):

My guess is

> ATOM

What am I? I am here

I am here,
yet most people don't care,

> Coz its everywhere

I kill people,
if you are not careful.

> If it belongs to an radioactive element

I can be created,
but it's rather useless.

> Yes

If you can see me,
It's because of Him.

> LIGHT

What am I?

Comment: Nope. I wouldn't say electricity is useless.

Comment: Not atom, though your answer fits most of the clues.

Answer (score 0):

Is it...

> Antimatter?

I am here,

> Antimatter has been proved to exist

yet most people don't care,

> It is not very significant at the time

I kill people, if you are not careful.

> Upon contact with matter, antimatter will instantly annihilate itself and whatever matter it touched.

I can be created,

> Scientists have been able to create and study antimatter.

but it's rather useless.

> Antimatter does have practical applications. However, considering the properties of antiparticles and our current technology, it is nearly impossible to put antimatter to use.

If you can see me, It's because of Him.

> Let's say that "see" refers to the pronouncement of $c$, the speed of light constant in the equation $E=mc^2$. Antimatter was predicted to exist using the expanded form of $E=mc^2$, which is $E^2=m^2c^4$. And of course, as we all know, $E=mc^2$ was discovered by Albert Einstein ("Him").

Comment: The last point violates the hint.

Comment: As ace said, last point doesn't match. I'm not looking for something that deep. It's a general knowledge question.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, newish here, so I'll take a long shot stab at this :)

> Are you bacteria/germs ?

I am here,
yet most people don't care,

> most people carry on without worrying to much about bacteria.
>  Sure, we wash our hands and such, but mostly we "don't care".

I kill people,
if you are not careful.

> some bacteria can lead to sickness/death if you're not careful
>  can think of some extreme situations, such as during operations, or spreading of a cold/flu

I can be created,
but it's rather useless.

> we can create bacteria and diseases:
>  http://www.sciencemag.org/content/329/5987/52.abstract
>  (not convinced of the useless part though :( )

If you can see me,
It's because of Him.

> if you can see something that smaller, it's likely via the aid of a Microscope or such.
>  (still not 100% what "Him" is referring, but if we call the Microscope "Him" ... :)

Comment: Him actually refers to a living person.

Comment: is the person still alive?