# Guess who I am: Born with a "spark"

Tags: riddle, knowledge

Energy can only be manipulated and moved, but never created or destroyed.

The two halves, they complement each other,

And yet are complete opposites.

I wish I was a channeler,

Born with a "spark"

But here I am asking other questions,

and answering them as best I can.

It's my "spark" I guess.

Comment: but energy in whole universe remains constant.:)

Comment: It's worth checking - do you really mean "compliment each other", or do you actually mean "complement each other"? The first one means that they say nice things to each other, the second one means they go well together and form a whole.

Comment: Complement, would be my guess, and it goes along with an answer I came up with(and got beaten to)

Comment: I added the trivia tag as specific uncommon knowledge was required. I suggest that you include this tag in future questions where the topics are not generally know (and are required for the answer)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't keep a good Wheel of Time fan down...

*Energy can only be manipulated and moved, but never created or destroyed.*

> This is the law of conservation of energy (see also [here](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/14655/5373), which I guess motivated this question).

*The two halves, they compliment each other,*

> [Saidin](http://wot.wikia.com/wiki/Saidin) and [saidar](http://wot.wikia.com/wiki/Saidar), the two halves of [the One Power](http://wot.wikia.com/wiki/One_Power).

*And yet are complete opposites.*

> Saidin and saidar differ in many ways but are basically two halves of the same thing.

*I wish I was a channeler,*

> People who can use the One Power are called [channelers](http://wot.wikia.com/wiki/Channeler).

*Born with a "spark"*

> Some channelers are born with the [spark](http://wot.wikia.com/wiki/Spark), meaning they'll inevitably begin to channel with or without training - if not found and trained e.g. by Aes Sedai, they usually die.

*But here I am asking other questions,*

*and answering them as best I can.*

> That's exactly what you're doing on the Puzzling Stack Exchange!

*It's my "spark" I guess.*

You are

> Gracelyn Rioux, a non-Aes Sedai.

I am

> [Rand al'Thor](http://wot.wikia.com/wiki/Rand_al'Thor), the [Dragon Reborn](http://wot.wikia.com/wiki/Dragon_Reborn) and the most powerful channeler alive :-D

Comment: Your profile has quite a bit on this book...  Seems like you would know.  :)

Comment: >_<    I'm still on 8th book. started reading them slowwwwly back in January

Comment: @Spacemonkey 8 books in 5 months is impressive! I've nearly finished book 10 atm.

Comment: I thought that since I didn't know what to write a riddle about I might as well write one about something I know pretty well… and then I saw rand al'thor's profile… nice job!

Comment: @GracelynRioux Wow ... I was half-joking when I wrote this! The word "channeler" was the giveaway.

Comment: @GracelynRioux If you were an Aes Sedai, what Ajah would you be? :-) PS. You should check out the SciFi & Fantasy SE; judging from your new profile, it'd be right up your street!

Comment: @rand al'thor Green! Well, I'd like to think that, but probably more like white or blue, I think

Answer (score 2):

I think the answer is:

> yin and yang

Energy can only be manipulated and moved, but never created or destroyed.

> They are depended on one an other and are always in balance.

The two halves, they compliment each other,

> well that's the whole idea about it.

And yet are complete opposites.

> good and evil, light and dark, fire and water, and male and female)

I wish I was a channeler,

> what is a channeler? someone that can channel both good and evil 'spirits'?

Born with a "spark"

But here I am asking other questions,

and answering them as best I can.

> it is an answer to what life is

It's my "spark" I guess.

Comment: Some explanation is always preferred.

Comment: @kaine happy now? can't i be lazy for once and add explanation if OP says i'm correct.

Comment: @Vincent_Advocaat Yes, the answer came up in the review as being of potentially poor quality and answers without an explanation should be deleted.  I figured it was less offensive to comment than to vote to delete the answer.

Comment: Saidar and saidin (see my answer) _were_ partly based on yin and yang from eastern philosophy...

Answer (score 1):

> Potential and Kinetic Energy.
>  They do complement. Two halves (metaphorically) of Mechanical Energy (Ideal Case, where it is equal to Total Energy). Potential Energy can be the channeler.

Comment: Interesting answer, +1 for you.