# Riddle from the one-eyed king

Tags: riddle, word, letters

*Complete me one way - if you do this to friends, you must have many enemies.

Complete me another - if you're tough you'll do this to your enemies.

Yet in a third way - with this you can keep your enemies from you.

And in a fourth way - with this you can always defeat your enemies.*

What are these words so entwined with enemies?

Hint/clarification:

> in each line, "completing me" refers to adding a **single** letter (a different letter in each line).

Hint 2:

> VOWELS

Comment: Is the answer starts with 'C'?

Comment: @Alex Nope, 'fraid not.

Comment: I have to ask. Is the title of the question related to a common interest that you and I mentioned on a different SE community?

Comment: @chaslyfromUK Not at all, but I like the fact that you're going to tantalise people by asking in such a roundabout and riddlish way! :-)

Comment: Haha! Title of the first! Plus the hero.Plus another Tavern fellow.

Comment: @chaslyfromUK Check [this](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/14896/5373) out!

Comment: @Gah! I can't do it! I can invent riddles but not solve them. Obviously I get the references but I can't quite put them together to make a whole. I'm not going to cheat, I'm hooked on that one now! Never mind, I'll concentrate on this one for the moment.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26728/discussion-between-chasly-from-uk-and-rand-althor).

Comment: Does that mean adding one letter with each line? Or is the base word same and we're just altering one letter at a time?

Comment: @CodeNewbie "Complete me one way" or "Complete me another" - in each line we apply a different operation to the same ground state.

Comment: E.g. Might, fight, eight, etc. or things like fire, free where the letter can be added in a different place?

Comment: @AndrewSmith Might, fight, eight is the right form of the solution; fire, free, etc. as h34 suggested isn't.

Comment: When you ask "What is this word so entwined", am I to believe that the string, like "ight" above, is a word itself also? Or could it also say "What are *these words* so entwined?

Comment: @Roland Another good point! No, the 'ground state' string isn't a word in itself. You're right that "these words" would be better; I'll edit.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer could be

> L _ C K

If you do this to friends, you must have many enemies.

> If you L**A**CK friends, you might have more enemies.

If you're tough you'll do this to your enemies.

> To [L**I**CK](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/lick?s=t) is defined informally as "to defeat" or "to hit/beat".

With this you can keep your enemies from you.

> With a decent L**O**CK, you could hide indefinitely from them.

With this you can always defeat your enemies

> With L**U**CK, who needs skill?

Comment: Very dodgy! :-) If you hail friends, you must have many enemies? With a halo you can keep your enemies from you? Also I've said already (I think it was only in comments and not as a hint in the OP - sorry) that in each line the new letter has to be added *in the same place*.

Comment: Yeah, just tryin' to see if I can move the inserted letter. Now I know.

Comment: I switched my answer, any comments, rand al'thor?

Comment: You got it! Well done :-D

Comment: And I disregarded LUCK being the answer to the last one many times. @randal'thor how does doing LACK to your friends make you have many enemies?

Comment: Funny, LUCK is the word that made me pretty sure I had it. And regarding LACK, a riddler wouldn't say "*this*ing your friends" when *this* is a verb with a direct object. "Doing *this*", where *this* is LACK, means *LACKING*, where the direct object is your friends. I would have switched "must have many" to "might have many", but for native English speakers at least, this makes sense.

Comment: I'm a native English speaker and "lack" being a verb that you do to something is blowing my mind lol. I'd have said that you do it of something rather than to something.

Comment: Yeah, there might not be a great way to hint at a verb that isn't an action verb.

Comment: Ah, I though it had to end with the letter, I have been a fool! A faulty interpretation of "complete" I suppose.

Comment: @AndrewSmith If you do X to your friends, then you X your friends - that was my thinking. Sorry if my wording threw you off the right answer!

Answer (score 2):

Complete me one way - if you do this to friends, you must have many enemies.

> If you LOWER your friends you will make lots of enemies

Complete me another - if you're tough you'll do this to your enemies.

> You will make them COWER

Yet in a third way - with this you can keep your enemies from you.

> You can defend yourself in a TOWER

And in a fourth way - with this you can always defeat your enemies.

> You can defeat your enemies with POWER

Comment: +1; you're the closest yet in terms of method. This answer would actually fit except for the second line: you don't cower your enemies! *OWER isn't right though, so don't bother looking for something else of that form that would fit the second line :-)

Comment: Ah I read that as something that they do from your tough actions, rather than an action that you do to them. I'll keep thinking

Comment: Baste/taste, waste, paste and haste seem to fit - but I doubt you intended on the enemies being kept at bay with some paste :D - nor for your friends to be delicacies ;)

Comment: @randal'thor a hint would be good right now :D

Comment: Always ready to oblige, my good sir! Check the question again :-)

Answer (score 1):

I believe the answer is

> Fo

Complete me one way - if you do this to friends, you must have many enemies.

> Foment

Complete me another - if you're tough you'll do this to your enemies.

> Forgive

Yet in a third way - with this you can keep your enemies from you.

> Foil

And in a fourth way - with this you can always defeat your enemies.

> Force

Comment: The first two clues are a bit dodgy... Also, if adding *any* number of letters is OK, then there's loads of things that could be shoehorned into fitting the riddle. That's my fault, I guess, so sorry for that! I've now updated with a hint/clarification.

Comment: Strange, because the first two were the ones I got first. Also, I figured that "Fo" would be appropriate for "Foemen".

Answer (score 1):

I think the answer is

> ARSE

"Riddle from the one-eyed king"

> What can that mean other than an arse? If it weren't for this clue in the title, EARS or SEAR or the unordered set {A, E, R, S} would do.

"Complete me one way - if you do this to friends, you must have many enemies."

> Add M to get SMEAR, or T to get TASER. If that's how you treat friends, they will soon stop being your friends and may become your enemies.

"Complete me another - if you're tough you'll do this to your enemies."

> Add C to get SCARE.

"Yet in a third way - with this you can keep your enemies from you."

> Add P to get SPEAR. Adding B to get SABRE might be less successful.

"And in a fourth way - with this you can always defeat your enemies."

> Add N to get SNARE.

"What is this word so entwined with foemen?"

> I can't get this bit. If it's a crossword-type clue, *so entwined with foemen* could give AS (synonym of SO) and perhaps RE can be got from *foemen* somehow, and then we entwine them together.

Comment: And another arse shows up ;)

Comment: @Avigrail Yes, that arse keeps showing up on my questions! :-o

Answer (score 0):

> I interpret this as words of the form KI**, with the base word as ki, which is another spelling of chi

Complete me one way - if you do this to friends, you must have many enemies.

> **KILL** ... I feel like the causation might be self explanatory

Complete me another - if you're tough you'll do this to your enemies.

> **KISS** ... Nothing is harder than reconciliation with a foe

Yet in a third way - with this you can keep your enemies from you.

> **KICK** ... excellent maneuver for creating distance in a fight

And in a fourth way - with this you can always defeat your enemies.

> **KIND** ... Kill'em with kindness fellas

Comment: The explanations for the second and fourth clues aren't too convincing... +1 for a good try though. And just to clear one thing up, there isn't necessarily a 'base word': what's left when 'I' am not 'completed' doesn't have to be an actual word.

Comment: @randal'thor Ah the "What is this word so entwined with foemen" part got me

Comment: I've updated the question with a hint/clarification. Sorry I didn't put that originally; it probably is 'too broad' without it.